# simpelst way to move an image over an image; with position

Tags: android, android-layout

i have an Activity whitch holds an image.
my goal is to draw and move a second image over the first one
performance is not important; which is the simplest and easyst way to create this ?

`ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.battery_horizontal_80percent );`

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
img.draw(c);
```

this code wont work :\

thanks !

Comment: Try [this][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972927/how-to-place-an-image-over-another-one-on-android-app

Comment: if i use this layout type, can i then set the second image to absolute x/y coords ?

Comment: ok .. finally i did it like this
http://micropilot.tistory.com/entry/Android-Image-Drawing-using-Canvas

Comment: Erwin please submit this as a answer and accept it so that it gets noticed quickly.

Comment: where is the button - the link- i dont see it ..

Comment: Erwin, please add ur link and peace of code as answer and then post ur answer and accept same.